# Why does the source code of Vim have a folder named farsi in the root directory?

Tags: history-of, vim-development

While looking through Vim's source code, I notice that it contained a folder named [`farsi`](https://github.com/vim/vim/tree/master/farsi) in the top directory, created 9 years ago. The [commit message](https://github.com/vim/vim/commits/master/farsi) seems to be just `updated for version 7.1a`. Why Farsi, and not any other language? And the location seems weird from a code organization perspective.

Answer (score 2):

It's just Farsi fonts, not code. The actual code lives in `src/farsi.c`, and is similar to `src/arabic.c`. Vim has shipped Farsi fonts since at least 1996 ([as separate download](ftp://ftp.vim.org/pub/vim/farsi/)).

Why does Vim ship with Farsi fonts but not Arabic fonts? Perhaps in 1996 Farsi fonts were not commonly shipped with OS's (and Arabic was), or perhaps it's a random inconsistent decision at the whim of Bram or another programmer ;-)